# Как записать байты в видео формат?

Tags: java, видео

Есть целое видео, я вырезаю из него середину. В итоге у меня массив байт, и когда я записываю его в файл, допустим, `movie.flv`, файл нельзя воспроизвести.

Как записать формат, *битрейт*, *фпс* в файл вместе с байтами на *java*?

Comment: Тебе это просто записать в файл, или все же сделать чтобы файл можно было проиграть?

Comment: просто так с произвольной позиции вырезать массив байт не получится. Видео это сложная формация с k-frame, b-frame и т.п. Проще вызвать ffmpeg и с его помощью вытащить нужный кусок.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov можно на java через ffmpeg скачать видео с удаленного сервера, взяв при этом определенную его часть, 40-47 секунды?

Comment: Я ваш ffmpeg с первого раза поставил всего-то за пол дня. ТС, учти это и запасись продовольствием.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь ffmpeg'ом. Вырезать часть видое записи можно следующим образом:

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i orginalfile -t 00:00:05 -vcodec copy -acodec copy newfile
```

В данном примере вырезаюстя 5 секунд начиная с 30-й секунды и сохраняется в виде отдельного файла.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сделал так Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "+url+" -t 00:00:05 -vcodec copy -acodec copy test.flv");